# Partition OVER field when grouping by another field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this table

```
ID  UPC Sales   Date    
1   333 10      1/1/2015
1   222 20      1/1/2015
1   111 30      1/1/2015
1   444 10      2/1/2015
1   555 20      2/1/2015
2   333 20      1/1/2015
2   222 50      1/1/2015
2   111 30      1/1/2015
2   444 20      2/1/2015
2   555 20      2/1/2015
```

And want this output

```
ID  SUM(Sales)  Avg(Sales)  COUNT(DISTINCT DATE)
1    90           45                2
2    140          70                2
```

I have tried this

```
SELECT ID, AVG(Sales) OVER (Partition BY Date) as basket_size
FROM Transactions 
GROUP BY ID
```

But I get this error:

> Column 'Transactions.Date' is invalid in the select list because it is
>   not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following would give you the desired result:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(ID INT,UPC INT, Sales INT, [Date] DATE);
INSERT INTO @t(ID,UPC,Sales,[Date])
VALUES(1,333,10,'2015-01-01'),
(1,222,20,'2015-01-01'),
(1,111,30,'2015-01-01'),
(1,444,10,'2015-01-02'),
(1,555,20,'2015-01-02'),
(2,333,20,'2015-01-01'),
(2,222,50,'2015-01-01'),
(2,111,30,'2015-01-01'),
(2,444,20,'2015-01-02'),
(2,555,20,'2015-01-02');

SELECT
    t1.ID,
    t1.[SUM(Sales)],
    t2.basket_size AS [AVG(Sales)],
    t1.[COUNT(DISTINCT Date)]
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ID,
            SUM(Sales) AS [SUM(Sales)],
            COUNT(DISTINCT [Date]) AS [COUNT(DISTINCT Date)]
        FROM
            @t
        GROUP BY
            ID
    ) AS t1
    INNER JOIN(
        SELECT
            ID,
            AVG([SUM(Sales)]) AS basket_size
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    ID,
                    [Date],
                    SUM(Sales) AS [SUM(Sales)]
                FROM
                    @t
                GROUP BY
                    ID,
                    [Date]
            ) AS tt
        GROUP BY    
            ID
    ) AS t2 ON
        t1.ID=t2.ID
```

Comment: @user2502836 Thinking a bit longer I came up with a more simple query :) : `SELECT ID, SUM(Sales) AS [sum], SUM(Sales)/COUNT(DISTINCT [Date]) AS [avg], COUNT(DISTINCT [Date]) AS [count] FROM @t GROUP BY ID;`. I believe this also to be correct for your requirements, only a lot simpler.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `OUTER APPLY`. Try this,

```
CREATE TABLE Transactions(ID INT, UPC INT, Sales INT, [Date] Date)

INSERT INTO Transactions(ID, UPC, Sales, [Date]) 
VALUES
(1,   333, 10,      '1/1/2015'),
(1,   222, 20,      '1/1/2015'),
(1,   111, 30,      '1/1/2015'),
(1,   444, 10,      '2/1/2015'),
(1,   555, 20,      '2/1/2015'),
(2,   333, 20,      '1/1/2015'),
(2,   222, 50,      '1/1/2015'),
(2,   111, 30,      '1/1/2015'),
(2,   444, 20,      '2/1/2015'),
(2,   555, 20,      '2/1/2015')

SELECT ID, SalesSum AS [Sum], SalesSum/[COUNT] AS AVG, [COUNT] AS [Count] FROM (
SELECT ID, Sum(Sales) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS SalesSum, [COUNT],
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) RN
FROM Transactions 
OUTER APPLY 
(
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [Date]) [COUNT] FROM Transactions 
) AS OUTR
) TMP WHERE RN = 1
```

[Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/182bc/6)